# If $a_n>0$ for all $n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+1}=A$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_na_{n+2}=B$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_na_{n+3}=C$, dis/prove $A=B=C$

Tags: calculus

I have hard time proving the following:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ and:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_na_{n+1}=A$$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_na_{n+2}=B$$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_na_{n+3}=C$$
>
> I try to prove or disprove that $A=B=C$.

So far I have managed to prove that $A=B$:

$$A^2=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n a_{n+1}\cdot\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_{n+2} a_{n+3} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}a_{n+3}\right)$$
$$B^2= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n a_{n+2}\cdot\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_{n+1}a_{n+3} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(a_n a_{n+1} a_{n+2}a_{n+3}\right)$$

So we get that $A^2=B^2$ and because $A,B$ are not negative we get that $A=B$.

Comment: You can just use the \$-sign like in LaTeX or two for an align-environment. So a_n becomes $a_n$.

Comment: Use braces: a_{n+2}. And you should edit the title so that it makes sense.

Comment: Consider $a_n = 2$ for even $n$ and $\frac{1}{2}$  for odd $n$. Then $A = C = 1$, but the limit $B$ does not exists. You will need stronger hypotheses on $a$  to get what you require.

Comment: But u know that B exist , u know that all does limits A,B,C exist(and finite)

Comment: Could  you add your proof of $A=B$?

Comment: Added a proof for A=B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt your prior argument to this new case, with a slightly more complicated product.

Observe that: $$
\begin{align}
A^3 &= \prod_{i = 0}^2\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\alpha_{n + 2i} \cdot \alpha_{n + 1 + 2i}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i = 0}^5\alpha_{n + i}\\
&= \prod_{i = 0}^2 \lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha_{n + i} \cdot \alpha_{n + 3 + i}\\
&= C^3
\end{align}
$$
As both $A$, $C$ are nonegative, taking cube roots yields $A = C$ as required.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Similarly, calculate $C^3$.

Comment: Thanks!! I solved it thanks to you